# Dynamic Formview with a dropdown list fails

Tags: c#, asp.net

188 Points

400 Posts

Dynamic Formview with a dropdown list fails horribly.

6 hours, 21 minutes ago|LINK

I've got concept in my head that I'm trying to materialize and it's not working. Here is what needs to happen: User selects a item from a list. Based on the selection a formview is built dynamically. The formview needs to be dynamic because the query will return a dataset with null values among non-null values such as this:

4600, 1, 4, NULL, NULL, 68 ....

The "4600" is model number and everything else is a ID that corresponds to a component. The Null values means that this filed does not belong to the 4600.

Henceforth, the formview then is build such that "4600" is fed to a label. For each non-null value I need to build a dropdown list, each with a separate datascource, not the ODS stuff, but a call to BLL class. Then the non-null value is assigned to the ddl's selected value property.

Simple enough, no? So here is the code and it's failing horribly. Actually just times out in an infinite loop. The time out happens in the ddlTonerBlack_DataBinding method. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks. EJM

aspx markup:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server"> 
<div> 
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlPrinterModels" AppendDataBoundItems="True" 
        DataTextField="Hardware_Model" DataValueField="Hardware_Model" 
        width="246px" CssClass="AssetMngnt-smallFont" AutoPostBack="true" > 
            <asp:ListItem Value="-1" Selected="True">-- Select Printer Model --</asp:ListItem> 
    </asp:DropDownList> 
    <hr /> 

    <asp:PlaceHolder id="DetailsViewPlaceHolder" runat="server"/> 

</div> 
<!-- NOT A COMPLETE QUERY --> 
<asp:sqldatasource id="ODSTonerBlackByModel" 
    selectcommand="SELECT [Hardware_Model], [Ident_Black], [Ident_Cyan], [Ident_Yellow] FROM [cPrinters_Toners] WHERE ([Hardware_Model] = @Hardware_Model)" 
    connectionstring="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CISF_Asset_Management %>" 
    runat="server"> 
    <SelectParameters> 
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlPrinterModels" Name="Hardware_Model" 
            PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" /> 
    </SelectParameters> 
</asp:SqlDataSource>  
</form>
```

Now the code file:

```
public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page 
{ 
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        if (!IsPostBack)  
        { 
            LoadData_PrinterModels();  
        } 

        FormView printerModelFormView = new FormView(); 

        dalConsumables_TonerBlack x = new dalConsumables_TonerBlack(); 

        printerModelFormView.ID = "fvPrinterModel"; 
        printerModelFormView.DataSourceID = "ODSTonerBlackByModel"; 

        printerModelFormView.PagerSettings.Mode = PagerButtons.NextPrevious; 
        printerModelFormView.HeaderText = "Printer Model"; 

        printerModelFormView.ItemTemplate = new FormViewTemplate(); 

        DetailsViewPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(printerModelFormView); 
    } 

    protected void LoadData_PrinterModels() 
    { 
        Printer_ModelsList x = new Printer_ModelsList(); 

        ddlPrinterModels.DataSource = x.GetPrinetr_Models(); 
        ddlPrinterModels.DataBind(); 
    } 

    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)  
    { 
        SqlDataSource sqlDS = new SqlDataSource(); 
        sqlDS.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CISF_Asset_Management"].ConnectionString; 
        sqlDS.SelectCommand = "SELECT dbo.cCartridge_Black.Ident_Black, dbo.cCartridge_Black.Model_Black, " + 
                               "dbo.cCartridge_Black.Desc_Black, dbo.cCartridge_Black.Qty_Black,  " + 
                               "dbo.cCartridge_Black.Black_Reorder_Limit, dbo.cCartridge_Black.Notes,  " + 
                               "dbo.cCartridge_Black.UpdatedBy, dbo.cPrinters_Toners.Hardware_Model " + 
                               "FROM   dbo.cCartridge_Black LEFT OUTER JOIN " + 
                               "dbo.cPrinters_Toners ON dbo.cCartridge_Black.Ident_Black  " + 
                               "= dbo.cPrinters_Toners.Ident_Black"; 
        form1.Controls.Add(sqlDS); 
        DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList(); 
        ddl.ID = "ddlTonerBlack"; 
        ddl.DataSource = sqlDS; 
        ddl.DataTextField = "Model_Black"; 
        ddl.DataValueField = "Ident_Black"; 
        form1.Controls.Add(ddl); 
    } 
}
```

And the template class:

```
public class FormViewTemplate : System.Web.UI.ITemplate 
{ 
    void System.Web.UI.ITemplate.InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control container) 
    { 
        Label lblPrinterModel = new Label(); 
        lblPrinterModel.ID = "lblHardwareModel"; 
        lblPrinterModel.DataBinding += new EventHandler(PrinterModelLabel_DataBinding); 

        container.Controls.Add(lblPrinterModel); 

        DropDownList ddlTonerBlack = new DropDownList(); 
        ddlTonerBlack.ID = "ddlTonerBlack"; 
        ddlTonerBlack.DataBinding +=new EventHandler(ddlTonerBlack_DataBinding); 

        container.Controls.Add(ddlTonerBlack); 
    } 

    private void PrinterModelLabel_DataBinding(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        Label lblPrinterModel = (Label)sender; 

        FormView formViewContainer = (FormView)lblPrinterModel.NamingContainer; 
        DataRowView rowView = (DataRowView)formViewContainer.DataItem; 

        lblPrinterModel.Text = rowView["Hardware_Model"].ToString(); 

    } 

    private void ddlTonerBlack_DataBinding(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        DropDownList ddlTonerBlack = (DropDownList)sender; 
        FormView formViewContainer = (FormView)ddlTonerBlack.NamingContainer; 
        DataRowView rowView = (DataRowView)formViewContainer.DataItem; 

        dalConsumables_TonerBlack x = new dalConsumables_TonerBlack(); 
        ddlTonerBlack.DataSource = x.GetListTonersBlack(); 
        ddlTonerBlack.DataBind(); 

        ddlTonerBlack.SelectedValue = rowView["Ident_Black"].ToString(); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get an infinite loop because in ddlTonerBlack_DataBinding method you call a DataBind method on the control that just fired a data bind event.

Simply you cause a databind event to fire in databind event handler of the same control and that's why you get an infinite loop.